# What is the technical term for this type of export?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have seen some people using export in this fashion,

```
export { default as Something } from './Something';
```

Is there any technical term for it?

Comment: I would call it a "named export, re-exporting `default` of `Something`", or "named re-export" for short. There's no technical term if you don't want to describe the syntax tree with the spec vocabulary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Re-exporting some module default's export aliasing it*.

Or: *re-exporting renaming default export*.